# Gitlab-ctl reconfigure fails after update: undefined method 'downcase'

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab, undefined

Unfortunately my gitlab server stopt working after an update yesterday.
I run `sudo update` then `sudo upgrade`.
Then the `gitlab-ctl connfigure` failed.

I allready searched a lot and try different Versions of the `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file.
When i take the standard gitlab.rb- file and only change the external path variable ill get the same error.
standard gitlab.rb:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/files/gitlab-config-template/gitlab.rb.template
I didnt find something usefull about my error. But there is a lot of info about the `undefined method [] for nil:NilClass` - Error. Is it something simular?

My gitlab instance is connectet with a reverse nginx proxy. And worked well before the update. My Operation System is Ubuntu 20.04.

And my gitlab page is still running. The only thing i cant do is to make a reconfigure.

I tried to downgrade to a previous (working) version of gitlab, but it doesnt change anything.

I really dont know what i have to do. Maybe some of you have an idea?

The Output:

```sh
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
Starting Chef Infra Client, version 15.14.0
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["gitlab"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - gitlab (0.0.1)
  - package (0.1.0)
  - logrotate (0.0.0)
  - postgresql (0.1.0)
  - redis (0.1.0)
  - registry (0.1.0)
  - monitoring (0.1.0)
  - mattermost (0.1.0)
  - consul (0.1.0)
  - gitaly (0.1.0)
  - praefect (0.1.0)
  - gitlab-kas (0.1.0)
  - gitlab-pages (0.1.0)
  - letsencrypt (0.1.0)
  - nginx (0.1.0)
  - runit (5.1.3)
  - acme (4.1.1)
  - crond (0.1.0)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
Recipe: gitlab::default
  * directory[/etc/gitlab] action create (up to date)

  ================================================================================
  Recipe Compile Error in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/default.rb
  ================================================================================

  NoMethodError
  -------------
  undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass

  Cookbook Trace:
  ---------------
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/libraries/helpers/redhat_helper.rb:40:in `get_redhatish_platform'
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/libraries/helpers/redhat_helper.rb:21:in `platform'
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/libraries/helpers/redhat_helper.rb:11:in `platform_family'
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/libraries/helpers/redhat_helper.rb:3:in `system_is_rhel7?'
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/selinux.rb:18:in `from_file'
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/default.rb:91:in `from_file'

  Relevant File Content:
  ----------------------
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/libraries/helpers/redhat_helper.rb:

   33:        'not redhat'
   34:      end
   35:    end
   36:
   37:    # Taken from Ohai
   38:    # https://github.com/chef/ohai/blob/v14.8.12/lib/ohai/plugins/linux/platform.rb#L23
   39:    def self.get_redhatish_platform(contents)
   40>>     contents[/^Red Hat/i] ? 'redhat' : contents[/(\w+)/i, 1].downcase
   41:    end
   42:
   43:    # Taken from Ohai
   44:    # https://github.com/chef/ohai/blob/v14.8.12/lib/ohai/plugins/linux/platform.rb#L34
   45:    def self.get_redhatish_version(contents)
   46:      contents[/Rawhide/i] ? contents[/((\d+) \(Rawhide\))/i, 1].downcase : contents[/(release)? ([\d\.]+)/, 2]
   47:    end
   48:  end
   49:

  System Info:
  ------------
  chef_version=15.14.0
  platform=ubuntu
  platform_version=20.04
  ruby=ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-linux]
  program_name=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client
  executable=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client


  Running handlers:
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass

  Running handlers complete
  Chef Infra Client failed. 0 resources updated in 04 seconds
```

/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out

```
  GNU nano 4.8                                                                                       /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Generated at 2021-02-06 09:24:12 +0100
NoMethodError: undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass
/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/libraries/helpers/redhat_helper.rb:40:in `get_redhatish_platform'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/libraries/helpers/redhat_helper.rb:21:in `platform'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/libraries/helpers/redhat_helper.rb:11:in `platform_family'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/libraries/helpers/redhat_helper.rb:3:in `system_is_rhel7?'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/selinux.rb:18:in `from_file'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/mixin/from_file.rb:34:in `instance_eval'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/mixin/from_file.rb:34:in `from_file'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/cookbook_version.rb:199:in `load_recipe'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/run_context.rb:393:in `load_recipe'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/run_context.rb:349:in `block in include_recipe'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/run_context.rb:348:in `each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/run_context.rb:348:in `include_recipe'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/dsl/include_recipe.rb:26:in `include_recipe'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/default.rb:91:in `from_file'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/mixin/from_file.rb:34:in `instance_eval'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/mixin/from_file.rb:34:in `from_file'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/cookbook_version.rb:199:in `load_recipe'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/run_context.rb:393:in `load_recipe'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:166:in `block in compile_recipes'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:163:in `each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:163:in `compile_recipes'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:79:in `compile'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/run_context.rb:223:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/policy_builder/expand_node_object.rb:103:in `setup_run_context'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable.rb:235:in `setup_run_context'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/client.rb:496:in `setup_run_context'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/client.rb:284:in `run'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/application.rb:320:in `run_with_graceful_exit_option'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/application.rb:296:in `block in run_chef_client'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:42:in `with_server_connectivity'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/application.rb:279:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/application/base.rb:330:in `run_application'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/application.rb:68:in `run'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-bin-15.14.0/bin/chef-client:25:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client:23:in `<main>'
```

reconfigure logfile:

```
# Logfile created on 2021-02-06 09:15:14 +0100 by logger.rb/v1.4.2
[2021-02-06T09:15:14+01:00] INFO: Started Chef Infra Zero at chefzero://localhost:1 with repository at /opt/gitlab/embedded
  One version per cookbook

[2021-02-06T09:15:14+01:00] INFO: *** Chef Infra Client 15.14.0 ***
[2021-02-06T09:15:14+01:00] INFO: Platform: x86_64-linux
[2021-02-06T09:15:14+01:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 634261
[2021-02-06T09:15:15+01:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[gitlab]"] from CLI options
[2021-02-06T09:15:16+01:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[gitlab]]
[2021-02-06T09:15:16+01:00] INFO: Run List expands to [gitlab]
[2021-02-06T09:15:16+01:00] INFO: Starting Chef Infra Client Run for kennis-HP-620
[2021-02-06T09:15:16+01:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2021-02-06T09:15:16+01:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2021-02-06T09:15:16+01:00] INFO: Loading cookbooks [gitlab@0.0.1, package@0.1.0, logrotate@0.0.0, postgresql@0.1.0, redis@0.1.0, monitoring@0.1.0, registry@0.1.0, mattermost@0.1.0, consul@0.1.0, gitaly@0.1.0, praefect@0.1.0, gitlab-kas@0.1.0, gitlab-pages@0.1.0, letsencrypt@0.1.0, nginx@0.1.0, runit@5.1.3, acme@4.1.1, crond@0.1.0]
[2021-02-06T09:15:18+01:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2021-02-06T09:15:18+01:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2021-02-06T09:15:18+01:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2021-02-06T09:15:18+01:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2021-02-06T09:15:18+01:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass
```

Best Regards!

Comment: Does nobody have an idea?
Or should i give more information about something?